# if I set `AllowOverride` to allow the use of .htaccess files, then how do I restrict Apache to not look for .htaccess in every directory?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

But just look in the specific directory to increase my webserver performance?

Apache always look for .htaccess in every directory if `AllowOverride` is set to `All`, so is there any directive to prevent Apache to not look in every directory?

Answer (score 0):

You should set allowoverride none on any directory (this configuration will include subdirectories) which you don't want to allow overriding.

Comment: this is either paradox or oxymoron answer.. beacause I said **"if I set `AllowOverride` to allow the use of .htaccess files"**